# Powershell : Get-ChildItem throw "path too long" error despite my path are short

Tags: powershell, path

I am facing a strange error in powershell. I am currently trying to copy files from a serveur (say Z:) to a folder in my laptop.

I want to perform some check on each file that is why I do not want to use a robotcopy.

When i run the command

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Y:\ -Recurse | Select-Object FullNameLength
```

I get an error (in french) telling that the path is too long for some items (260 caracters). But I checked and the item path are not that long. For example

```
Y:\00.P1.2020.211-MEP 2020-11-01-RENOM\06 - Chantier
```

My Y:\ is a sharepoint online linked as a network drive.

Do you know where it could come from

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Well it comes from the fact that a smart guy had put a file with a name of 308 characters in the folder. So I wasn't even able to see it in the explorer but it was still there (in the sharepoint) to raise the error.

I let it there if it can help someone else